# Limitations of survival analysis

Tags: survival

I am learning about survival analysis in health care research. I have read a lot about the advantages, but not the disadvantages.

So my question is what are the limitations to applying survival analysis techniques to health research?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is an interesting question but in my opinion rather too broad for our Q&A format. Over *what* does survival analysis have advantages? Are there particular techniques you have in mind? Making it more specific would I think improve the chances of getting clear, useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are *some* limitations:

**Censoring Assumptions:** Requires assumptions about censored data that may not reflect reality, potentially biasing results.

**Complexity for Non-Statisticians:** Interpretation and implementation can be difficult for practitioners without statistical knowledge.

**Modelling of Time-Dependent Covariates:** Incorporating time-varying factors can be complex and may lead to model misspecification.

**High Variability with Small Sample Sizes:** As with many other models, estimates can be unstable with small numbers of events or a high censoring rate.

**Non-Identifiability of Late Risks:** Late risks may be difficult to estimate accurately due to censoring.

**Assumption of Independent Censoring:** Assumes censoring is unrelated to prognosis, which may not always be true.

**Difficulty Handling Multiple Events:** Complications arise when individuals can experience more than one type of event.

**Competing Risks:** Standard methods do not account for competing risks, which can lead to biased risk estimates.

**Data Quality and Completeness:** Requires high-quality, complete data over follow-up periods, which may be difficult to obtain.

**Challenges with Rare Events:** With events that are rare, survival analysis may struggle with power and precision.

**Parametric Model Assumptions:** Parametric survival models rely on assumptions about the distribution of survival times that may be incorrect.

**Subject to Overfitting:** Like all regression analyses, can overfit data especially when including numerous covariates.

**Sensitive to Outliers:** Outliers can disproportionately influence model results, leading to skewed interpretations.